# parsing json with using json.net linq

Tags: c#, json.net

I tray to parse json with using Json.Net but  i am new parsing json and i didn't get good result after so many test.

json structure is as below;

```
 [
   {
      "Coo":{
         "id":"1"
      },
      "Hor":{
         "name":"Poo"
      },
      "Vor":{
         "name":"Soo"
      },
      "Status":"1",
      "Tola":[
         {
            "value":"10",
         },
         {
            "value":"20",
         }
      ],
      "Opt":[

      ]
   },
   {
      "Coo":{
         "id":"2"
      },
      "Hor":{
         "name":"Zoo"
      },
      "Vor":{
         "name":"Koo"
      },
      "Status":"2",
      "Tola":[
         {
            "value":"20",
         },
         {
            "value":"10",
         }
      ],
      "Opt":[

      ]
   },
      {
      "Coo":{
         "id":"3"
      },
      "Hor":{
         "name":"Moo"
      },
      "Vor":{
         "name":"Noo"
      },
      "Status":"1",
      "Tola":[
         {
            "value":"30",
         },
         {
            "value":"20",
         }
      ],
      "Opt":[

      ]
   }
]
```

My code is as below for parsing.

```
_JsonString = _JsonString.Trim().Trim('[',']');

JObject _JObject = JObject.Parse(_JsonString);

var _JItems = _JObject.SelectToken(".")
             .Select(s => new
             {
                 _Id = (string)s.SelectToken("Coo.id"),
                 _WhereClause = (string)s.SelectToken("Status")
             })
             .Where(w => w._WhereClause == "1");

foreach (var _JItem in _JItems)
{
    MessageBox.Show(_JItem._Id.ToString());
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What exactly are the issues you have? What is wrong with the result?

Comment: your code is very hard to read because you use upper case for local variables.

Comment: @Patrick Hofman result must return 1 and 3 in for block. But I am getting nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `JObject` while you should use `JArray`:

Remove this line:

```
_JsonString = _JsonString.Trim().Trim('[', ']'); /*removed*/
```

And change

```
JObject _JObject = JObject.Parse(_JsonString);
```

To

```
JArray _JObject = JArray.Parse(_JsonString);
```

**Full code:**

```
JArray _JObject = JArray.Parse(_JsonString);

var _JItems = _JObject.SelectToken(".")
             .Select(s => new
             {
                 _Id = (string)s.SelectToken("Coo.id"),
                 _WhereClause = (string)s.SelectToken("Status")
             })
             .Where(w => w._WhereClause == "1");

foreach (var _JItem in _JItems)
{
    MessageBox.Show(_JItem._Id.ToString());
}
```

Comment: I have tried that but I couldn't implement to my code. Could you give an example?

Comment: What is the problem with it? This is your example with two modifications.